# Generating Intellitrace log file for Azure Service Fabric On Premise

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-diagnostics, intellitrace

We have services (stateful/stateless) running on premise with 5 nodes cluster. In production environment, I would like to log diagnostic events/trace event into log file for further analyze in VS 2019 Enterprise edition.

How do I achieve that, as I can't find collection method such as

```
{
Start-IntelliTraceCollection "FabrikamFiber.Extranet.Web" c:\IntelliTrace\collection_plan.ASP.NET.trace.xml c:\LogFileLocation
}
```

Comment: cross posted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d495945-e56b-4045-a0e0-5698bf5e50f4/intellitrace-setup-for-azre-service-fabric-onpremise?forum=AzureServiceFabric

Answer (score 0):

The command "Start-IntelliTraceCollection" is in the IntelliTrace standalone package 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-intellitrace-stand-alone-collector?view=vs-2019.

That means 
1. Upload the standalone package to your nodes.
2. Import the powershell module Import-Module "C:\IntelliTraceCollector\Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.PowerShell.dll"
3. Then you can use the command you post.

Be aware that the powershell module works for web application and sharepoint application.

For other types of application, you can use IntelliTraceCollectorIntelliTraceSC.exe

You should find more details from the above link.